# Firestore Google Data Studio

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, looker-studio

I'm trying to connect firestore with data studio, use is connector made by the community but does not work.

This is the error message
Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

is there any alternative for this integration?

Answer (score 2):

We have temporarily removed the Firestore connector from the gallery since it requires sensitive OAuth scopes. As the code is available in our repo, we recommend you deploy the code yourself to use the connector.

repo: https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors

deployment guide: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/deploy

Comment: Thank you, Another solution may be to send my data with cloud functions to bigQuery and connect data studio with bigQuery?

Comment: Sure. That could be an option also. But that might need some extra legwork.